# Unexpected results from loop in tagui

Tags: rpa

I use a simple code describing basic usage of a loop in tagui but the result is unexpected. Could you help me understand what went wrong and how to fix this?

I tried to replicate basic example from that website: https://www.rpa-sg.org/TagUI-Commands/for.php

```
for (n=0; n<10; n+=2)

{
    echo "n = " + n
}
```

expected result is

```
n = 0

n = 2

n = 4

n = 6

n = 8
```

actual result:

```
START - automation started - Thu Sep 12 2019 14:06:53 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)

n = 10

FINISH - automation finished - 0.3s
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from invisible characters copied away with copy paste of the code from the web. More reference from the direct support of Ken Soh here [github issue][1]https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/565